# AffinityPropagation' object has no attribute 'label_'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using scikit learn for affinity propogation algo. My input data is a numpy array of size 2303*2303 . It is a similarity matrix. I want to calculate the distance of each element in a cluster to its centroid. When i try to print the labels, i am getting the following error:

"AffinityPropagation' object has no attribute 'label_'". Here is the code:

```
    clusterer = AffinityPropagation(affinity = 'precomputed')
    af = clusterer.fit(l2)
    print af.label_
```

I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'AffinityPropagation' object has no attribute 'label_'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs of [AffinityPropagation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AffinityPropagation.html) you have to type

`print af.labels_`

Comment: this was such a stupid mistake. Thanks for correcting.